# Is there a method to reliably distinguish cdata from ctypes?

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

I'm the author of a library which needs to treat cdata and ctypes differently. At the moment, I use `ffi.typeof(value) == value`, but that gives an error for some cdata with a metatable that defines `__eq`. The user who filed this bug report suggested checking for `tostring(value):match"^ctype"` instead but that just shifts the problem to cdata with a metatable that defines `__tostring`. I've tried `rawequal` but my original condition relied on meta magic in the first place, so that doesn't work at all.

I'm considering using `local success, eq = pcall(function() return ffi.typeof(value) == value end)` and using the condition `success and eq`, but I wonder: is there a more reliable, less hack-y way to achieve this?

Comment: What kind of cdata are you working with? Are they all structures/arrays? Or simple cdata values (such as `123LL` or `0i`) are also allowed?

Comment: Any and all cdata is allowed, it's a serialization library that's designed to handle basically whatever the library users could want to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below is also hack-y, but it might be interesting to you.
It abuses the undocumented feature that `tonumber()` is applicable to ctypes.

```
local function is_ctype(x)
   return type(x) == "cdata"
      and tonumber(x) ~= nil
      and tostring(x):sub(1,5) == "ctype"
end
```

Please note that `tostring()` is applied only to cdata convertible to numbers.
`ctype<complex>` is the only metatype-able ctype whose values are convertible to numbers.
Happily, `ctype<complex>` does not respect `__tostring` metamethod. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This also bugged me some time ago, here is what I got so far.

The code works for my use-cases but it does not handle this edge case:

```lua
assert(ffi.new("int", 9) == ffi.typeof("int")) --> this assertion is true.
```

I couldn't find a way around this, I assume that's just how LuaJIT works.
The same happens for all the other basic types as well (with their respective ids)

Full code:

```lua
local ffi = require "ffi"

function isctype(o)
    -- ctypes can be converted to a number
    local check = tonumber(o)
    if check == nil then
        return false
    end

    -- typeinfo expects a number, we have a number
    local maybeInfo = ffi.typeinfo(check)
    local sureInfo = ffi.typeinfo(ffi.typeof(o))

    -- type infos differ
    if maybeInfo.info ~= sureInfo.info then
        return false
    end

    local type = ffi.typeof(o)

    -- No way around this except calling tostring(o)
    -- which would have it's own drawbacks.

    -- When we got here we have the special case
    -- that the type-id is equal to the result
    -- of tonumber(o).
    -- this happens e.g. for typeof"int" and 9.
    -- In this case the result is also true,
    -- which is actually not quite what I'd expect.

    return o == type
end

local ct = ffi.typeof("struct { int x; }")

print("type", isctype(ct)) --> true
print("data", isctype(ffi.new(ct))) --> false
print("type", isctype(ffi.typeof("int"))) --> true
print("type", isctype(ffi.typeof("const char*"))) --> true
print("data", isctype(ffi.new("float", 3))) --> false
print("data", isctype(ffi.new("int", 3))) --> false
print("data", isctype(ffi.new("intptr_t", 3))) --> false
print("data", isctype(ffi.new("int[1]", 3))) --> false
print("data", isctype(ffi.new("const char*", "yo"))) --> false
print("data", isctype(ffi.new("int", 8))) --> false

-- this is sad :(
print("data", isctype(ffi.new("int", 9))) --> true

assert(ffi.new("int", 9) == ffi.typeof("int"))

print("assertion did not fail :(")
```